# Gson Converted data not set in Recyclerview using Retrofit2

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

Gson Convertable data is not set in Recyclerview using Retrofit2 and rxjava2 then its Give Error:

"kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property compositeDisposable has not been initialized"

MainActivity.kt

```
internal lateinit var api : APIInterface

lateinit var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable

internal lateinit var companyDialog : Dialog

internal lateinit var companyAdapter: CompanyAdapter

internal lateinit var data : List<Company>


fun showCompanyPopupView(){
    companyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.compny_popup_screen)

    val rvCompany : RecyclerView = companyDialog.findViewById(R.id.rvCompany)

    rvCompany.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rvCompany.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    fetchData()
    companyDialog.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    companyDialog.show()
}

private fun fetchData(){

    val retrofit = APIClient.apIClient
    if (retrofit != null) {
        api = retrofit.create(APIInterface::class.java)
    }
    compositeDisposable.add(api.getCompanyData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe ({ companyList-> displayData(data)
            },{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })

    )

}


private fun displayData(companyList: List<Company>) {


    val adapter = CompanyAdapter(this,companyList)
    rvCompany.adapter = adapter

}
```

CompanyAdapter.kt

class CompanyAdapter(internal var context: Context, internal var companyList: List)
    :RecyclerView.Adapter(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CompanyViewHolder {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

```
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item,p0,false)

    return CompanyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    return companyList?.size!!
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: CompanyViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

   // p0.rbButton.text = this!!.companyList?.get(p1)?.Cmp_Name
    p0.bindModel(companyList[p1])
}

inner class CompanyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    val radioButton : RadioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbCompanyName)

    fun bindModel(company: Company){

        radioButton.text = company.Cmp_Name
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The error is very well described, you're using your variable compositeDisposable before initializing it.

Just initialize your variable this way before you call it:

```
internal lateinit var api : APIInterface

var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

internal lateinit var companyDialog : Dialog
internal lateinit var companyAdapter: CompanyAdapter
internal lateinit var data : List<Company>

fun showCompanyPopupView(){
 companyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.compny_popup_screen)

 val rvCompany : RecyclerView = companyDialog.findViewById(R.id.rvCompany)

 rvCompany.setHasFixedSize(true)
 rvCompany.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

 fetchData()
 companyDialog.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
 companyDialog.show()
}

private fun fetchData(){
   val retrofit = APIClient.apIClient

   if (retrofit != null) {
    api = retrofit.create(APIInterface::class.java)
  }

  compositeDisposable.add(api.getCompanyData()
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe ({ companyList-> displayData(data)
      },{
          Toast.makeText(applicationContext, it.message, 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      })
   )
}
```

Comment: now its give,kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property data has not been initialized error

Comment: This is the exact same error. You didn't initialized your variable data before use it. I suggest you to read [this guide about lateinit](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/kotlin-when-to-use-lazy-or-lateinit/) to know how to properly use it